# Multiple spring events in two different transactions are not received in the same order of committing the two transactions

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am using the `@TransactionalEventListener` to listen for published events in spring boot.
I have two different methods annotated with `@Transactional` that publish the same type of events I am listening on. I am using a pessimistic write lock on both methods to ensure consistency, so when two requests, one for each method, are received at the same time, one method blocks the other until it commits.

When a request for method 1 is received first and it is taking a long time to finish and in the middle a request for method 2 is received, it is blocked until method 1 finishes.

My problem is that the events published by each method are not received by the listener in the same order of committing the results. I mean events for method 1 are received after events of method 2.